Is it possible to display emoji inside JavaFX TextArea?
I need an emoji along with text editing support, but when I insert any emoji in the text area (no matter if via code or via clipboard) it doesn't display at all. I tried downloading NotoColorEmoji font and setting it for the text area, but again nothing is displayed. Moreover, this font only contains emoji, so regular characters are not displayed as well.
var url = getClass().getResource("NotoColorEmoji-Regular.ttf").toExternalForm();
var ta = new TextArea("");
ta.setFont(Font.loadFont(url, 12));

I know about 3rd party libs, but they can't all be used for various reasons. So, please, don't recommend any of them.
Is there a way to get emoji support in standard text input control? Any workarounds?
UPDATE:
TL;DR: I think it's a JavaFX bug. Some emoji fonts fully/partially cannot be rendered. Those that do only rendered as greyscale.
Environment: Ubuntu 22.04 (KDE 5.24) or Fedora 39 (KDE 5.27), JDK/JFX 21 or JDK/JFX 22 (latest)
Out-of-the-box, both Ubuntu and Fedora use the 'Noto Color Emoji' font, which cannot be rendered by JavaFX. Most symbols are missing.
JavaFX has own font renderer engine which reads the Linux font config settings. It's easy to check by not closing the XML tag. You'll get a JavaFX warning on startup.
So I downloaded all the available emoji TTF fonts and tried them out. To change the font, you need to put the TTF files in ~/.fonts and the configuration in ~/.config/fontconfig.
 <match>
  <test name="family">
   <string>sans-serif</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" name="family" mode="prepend">
   <string>Segoe UI Emoji</string>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match>
  <test name="family">
   <string>serif</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" name="family" mode="prepend">
   <string>Segoe UI Emoji</string>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <match>
  <test name="family">
   <string>monospace</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" name="family" mode="prepend">
   <string>Segoe UI Emoji</string>
  </edit>
 </match>
 <!-- optionally override system emoji font -->
 <match>
  <test name="family">
   <string>Noto Emoji</string>
  </test>
  <edit binding="strong" name="family" mode="prepend">
   <string>Segoe UI Emoji</string>
  </edit>
 </match>

Here is the test node:
var eta = new TextArea("""
                                           
                       ‍   ‍      ☹️           
                                           
                                           
                                
                """);

.root {
    -fx-font-family: "serif";
}


Twitter Emoji, https://github.com/13rac1/twemoji-color-font
Apple Emoji, https://github.com/samuelngs/apple-emoji-linux
OpenSans Emoji, https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji
Noto Emoji, https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Color+Emoji

I also found a very similar bug for MacOS JDK-8290866, but unfortunately setting -Dprism.lcdtext=true as well as changing -fx-smoothing-type didn't help.
And the results:


Yes, JavaFX can display emojis. Using new TextArea("") with the default font displays the emojis for me (on Windows 11), just not with the color. But if I load the NotoColorEmoji font and set it on the text area, the emojis don't display (though they take up space). I'm not sure why that font is causing issues.

Thanks for the answers, so either Linux is out of luck or something is wrong with my font settings. Although every other editor has no problem displaying emoji.

Right.  The KEY POINT to remember is that emojis are nothing more than Unicode characters, just like any other characters in a string.  And just like any other foreign language, they will only display if the font you are using includes those glyphs.  You can't display Kanji using a font without Japanese planes, and you can't display emojis in a font without the emoji planes.

A [MCVE] might improve this Question.

Specify your version of Java. Specify your version of JavaFX. Specify your host OS.

@Tim While true, Noto Color Emoji is supposed to be able to display the emojis given (see preview), yet JavaFX apparently has some issues with the font.

Thanks everyone! I've filed a bug. Let's see if it gets accepted or not.

An example to demonstrate current behavior and summarize comments, showing how various emoji fonts are handled (not a comprehensive cross-platform answer).
I only ran the example app on OS X, other OS environments may exhibit different behavior.
OS X output
Environment

OS X 14.5
openJDK 22.0.2
JavaFX 22.0.2


Sample app
In the example app, the fonts required are downloaded dynamically at runtime, so they don't need to be pre-downloaded and installed in the OS for you to use them.  However, the drawback of this approach is that it takes a few seconds for the app to start as it gathers and initializes the fonts off of the net.
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class EmoApp extends Application {
    private static final String CSS_DATA = "data:text/css,";

    private static final String CSS = CSS_DATA + """
        .root {
           -fx-font-size: 16px;
        }
        .default {}
        .noto-color-emoji {
          -fx-font-family: "Noto Color Emoji";
        }
        .open-sans-emoji {
          -fx-font-family: "OpenSansEmoji";
        }
        .segoe-emoji {
          -fx-font-family: "Segoe UI Emoji";
        }
        .apple-color-emoji {
          -fx-font-family: "Apple Color Emoji";
        }
        """;

    private static final String EMOJI_TEXT = """
                                   
               ‍   ‍      ☹️           
                                   
                                   
                        
        """;


    private static final String NOTO_COLOR_EMOJI_CSS =
            "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Color+Emoji&display=swap";

    private static final List<String> emojiStyleClasses = List.of(
            "default",
            "noto-color-emoji",
            "open-sans-emoji",
            "segoe-emoji",
            "apple-color-emoji"
    );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Font.loadFont(
                "https://github.com/MorbZ/OpenSansEmoji/raw/master/OpenSansEmoji.ttf",
                10
        );
        Font.loadFont(
                "https://github.com/mrbvrz/segoe-ui/raw/master/font/seguiemj.ttf",
                10
        );

        VBox layout = new VBox(10);
        layout.getChildren().addAll(
                emojiStyleClasses.stream()
                        .map(this::emojiSample)
                        .toList()
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Scene scene = new Scene(layout);
        scene.getStylesheets().addAll(
                NOTO_COLOR_EMOJI_CSS,
                CSS
        );
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public Pane emojiSample(String styleClass) {
        TextArea textArea = new TextArea(EMOJI_TEXT);
        textArea.setPrefSize(750, 160);
        textArea.getStyleClass().add(styleClass);

        return new VBox(5,
                new Label(styleClass),
                textArea
        );
    }
}

Notes

From my testing (on Mac), the color Emojis only work with the default Mac Apple Color Emoji font and Mac appears to fall back to use that if the appropriate glyphs aren't in the requested font, but no other color fonts will work with JavaFX (they will be rendered monochrome or not at all).

If I run this code
stage.setScene(new Scene(new TextArea("\uD83D\uDE00\uD83D\uDE03\uD83D\uDE04"))); 

on a Mac, it works just fine, and the emojis you have in your question display. Also copy and paste of your emojis into the text area works fine as well as editing caret positioning, selection highlighting and the delete key.

On Mac the Emojis display in color, with the default system font. The standard "command + ctrl + space" keyboard sequence will bring up an emoji input selection in most Mac apps, but not in JavaFX apps. So I am not sure how to use the keyboard to enter new emojis.

To get multicolored emoji characters, you probably need to use a color font, e.g. on Windows, you could try "Segoe UI Emoji".  However, from my testing on Mac, JavaFX didn't seem to handle color fonts (except the "Apple Color Emoji" font that ships with the OS).

I know the asker doesn't want to use a third-party library, but for others who come across this question who do, you could consider pavlobu / emoji-text-flow-javafx, mentioned in this similar question and answer, which "allow users to use extended TextFlow to display emojis. It helps to display consistent emoji images on different platforms where JavaFX application runs."

I also tried it on Mac with the OpenSansEmoji font -> output was similar to that in the question, but (most glyphs rendered monochrome, but glyphs rendered garbled in the question were displayed in color, probably just falling back to the default Apple Emoji Font, which works). Similarly for Segoe UI Emoji, which renders many more black and white glyphs as shown in the question, and color default Apple Emoji Fonts for the glyphs not rendered in Segoe. Noto Color Emoji rendered blank characters on Mac.

So what that means to me is that JavaFX can only render the color emojis from the default Apple Emoji Font on a Mac, but not a custom color font. Probably there is some special fallback on Macs to use the Apple Emoji font if the current font doesn't have the appropriate Emoji glyphs. Still, outside of that, color glyphs aren't rendered (similar to Linux), so it is probably a cross-platform limitation of JavaFX font processing and not Linux-specific.


FAQ

How did you get the behavior of rendered monochrome or not at all if the Apple Color Emoji font is used as a fallback? Is there a way to prevent the fallback?

I didn't do anything to have that fallback behavior, it just seems to happen.  You can see in the result that some emoji fonts are rendering monochrome for glyphs, which is coming from the emoji font.  But when the emoji font does not seem to have an appropriate glyph you see color glyphs coming from the Apple emoji font.
The Noto Color Emoji font has all the glyphs, but they don't render with JavaFX, ending up with blank text.
Unrelated to JavaFX, the default emoji font used by Apple (Apple Emoji Font) can be replaced in the OS, see:

https://superuser.com/questions/968509/is-is-possible-to-change-the-emoji-set-on-os-x

The link (which is quite old), noted that the "Noto Color Emoji" font does not work on OS X, so the failure of the font may be at the OS level, rather than directly applicable to JavaFX.

Thanks for the detailed answer. I think your conclusion about MacOS is correct. I found this PR that specifically says "On other platforms the Emoji will be rendered as ordinary greyscale glyphs - if there is font support for the requested code point." And since devs have never tested emoji rendering with other fonts than MacOS, there are obviously font loading issues.

As for 3rd party TextFlow implementations, I think it's easier for now to use Gluon's Emoji (and RichTextArea for editing), but the latter is very buggy and not FOSS, so not really an alternative.

Likely your computer lacks a font with glyphs for those particular characters. Or you are using an older version of Java that did not support the necessary level of Unicode. Java 22 supports Unicode 15.1 per Release Notes.
To debug the situation, write a minimal app to demonstrate the problem.  Add several other characters from various parts of Unicode to see if they render.
In example below we add FACE WITH MEDICAL MASK, the King & Queen of chess, and your faces.
This example works on macOS Sonoma 14, with Java 22, and JavaFX 23-ea+22.
The content with TextArea:
package work.basil.example.exfx;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

public class EmojiPane extends VBox
{
    public EmojiPane ( )
    {
        var emojiTextArea = new TextArea( "Testing 1 2 3  Chess:♕♔ Faces:" ); // "" "" "♕♔"

        this.setPadding( new Insets( 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 ) );
        this.setSpacing( 10 );
        this.getChildren( ).addAll( emojiTextArea );
    }
}

And an app to exercise that code:
package work.basil.example.exfx;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start ( Stage stage ) throws IOException
    {
        Pane root  = new EmojiPane() ;
        Scene scene = new Scene( root , 300 , 250 );

        stage.setTitle( "Emoji" );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show( );
    }

    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        launch( );
    }
}

Just to be clear, here is my POM.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>work.basil.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ExFx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ExFx</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.10.2</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>23-ea+22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-fxml -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>23-ea+22</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.11.0-M2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.13.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>22</source>
                    <target>22</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>work.basil.example.exfx/work.basil.example.exfx.HelloApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

Screenshot:

You can edit that text, as well as paste emoji.
All emoji
We can modify our example app to display all emoji characters. Designating emoji characters is the job of the Unicode Consortium.
We loop all of the million code point range in Unicode. Then we use method Character.isEmoji to filter. In Java 22, we find 1,424.
Many more emoji are possible, by combining traits. We ignore that here, focusing on just the basics.
While I did not study extensively, in a quick scan my eye failed to notice any missing glyphs. Apple Inc. seems to have covered all the current emoji in one or more fonts bundled with macOS Sonoma 14.
By the way… We switched from VBox to BorderPane to make the text field auto-expand when window stretches.
Just swap out EmojiPane class for this version:
package work.basil.example.exfx;

import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class EmojiPane extends BorderPane
{
    public EmojiPane ( )
    {
        final String EM_SPACE = Character.toString( 8_195 );
        String emojis =
                IntStream
                        .rangeClosed( Character.MIN_CODE_POINT , Character.MAX_CODE_POINT )
                        .filter( Character :: isEmoji )
                        .mapToObj( codePoint -> Character.toString( codePoint ) + EM_SPACE + Character.getName( codePoint ) )
                        .collect( Collectors.joining( "\n" ) );
        var emojiTextArea = new TextArea( emojis.lines( ).count( ) + " emoji characters\n" + emojis );  // `emojis.lines().count()` is not efficient, but who cares.   "Testing 1 2 3  Chess:♕♔ Faces:" ); // "" "" "♕♔"

        this.setPadding( new Insets( 10 , 10 , 10 , 10 ) );
        this.setCenter( emojiTextArea );
    }
}


Thanks for the MWE. I always use recent Java(FX) versions. Updated question with more details.

@jewelsea How did you get the behavior of rendered monochrome or not at all if the Apple Color Emoji font is used as a fallback? Is there a way to prevent the fallback?

Replaced comments with an answer that collates the comments, provides some sample code I used based on the emojis in the question, and provides output for various fonts.
